# can't deply image from WDS server on multiple Virtual machines

Tags: deployment, windows-server-2016, windows-10, wds

**Background**: I have 3 test virtual machine, WDS+DHCP+DC and two client . when I'm going deploy win10 on one machine every things is okay .
I didn't change the default setting dhcp runs on port 67 and the pxboot option 60 is set.

**Problem** :but when I'm trying deploy two windows in same time ,they show an error "didn't reply request on port 4011" or there is not boot image !

thank you for help in advance.

Update:I manage to deploy image with disabling the netbios but when multicast configured, client don't use it.any idea why it does happen?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should check if you have enabled WINS on your Network card (under TCPv4 Settings) of your WDS Server.. When yes, disable it :)

[image]

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: because it is :) WDS on Server > 2008 R2 has this problem!